# Generate random color for every list element

Tags: jquery, json

I have got 4 points list.

I would like to generate random color for every element. I store colors in JSON.

JSON:

```
var myJson = [{   
"color":"#69bf64",  
"name":"Green",  
"namePL":["Zielony"]},    
{   
"color":"#f7f390",  
"name":"Yellow",  
"namePL":["Żółty"]}, 
{  ];
```

My list:

```
<ul id="answer">
    <li class="random">One</li>
    <li class="random">Two</li>
    <li class="random">Three</li>
    <li class="random">Four</li>
</ul>
```

Tried to do this in that way, but does not work.

```
for(var i =0;i < $('.random').length-1;i++)
{
   getColour = function(){
    var entry = myJson[Math.floor(Math.random()*myJson.length)];           
    return entry;      
   }
     var localObj = getColour();
     $('#random').css('color', localObj.color );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('.random').css('color', localObj.color );
```

You are using a `(#random)` which is used for IDs. Use `(.random)` is used for classes

Answer (score 0):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/oqb1zrdy/)***

Just use `.each` to iterate

```
$('.random').each(function(){
 $(this).css('color',myJson[Math.floor(Math.random()*myJson.length)].color);
});
```

*Stack Snippet Demo*

```js
var myJson = [{   
"color":"#69bf64",  
"name":"Green",  
"namePL":["Zielony"]},    
{   
"color":"#f7f390",  
"name":"Yellow",  
"namePL":["Żółty"]}, 
];
setInterval(function(){
$('.random').each(function(){
 $(this).css('color',myJson[Math.floor(Math.random()*myJson.length)].color);
});
},1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>sets random color every second to show changes</div>
<ul id="answer">
    <li class="random">One</li>
    <li class="random">Two</li>
    <li class="random">Three</li>
    <li class="random">Four</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want have different color for each li:

```js
    var myJson = [{   
    "color":"#69bf64",  
    "name":"Green",  
    "namePL":["Zielony"]},    
    {   
    "color":"#f7f390",  
    "name":"Yellow",  
    "namePL":["Żółty"]}, 
    {
    "color":"#cc0000",  
    "name":"Red",  
    "namePL":["czerwony"],
    },
    {
    "color":"#0000cc",  
    "name":"Blue",  
    "namePL":["niebieski"],
    }];


   for(var i =0;i < $('.random').length;i++){
       getColour = function(){
           var entry = myJson[Math.floor(Math.random()*myJson.length)];           
       return entry;      
       }
       var localObj = getColour();
       $('.random:eq('+i+')').css('color', localObj.color );
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="answer">
    <li class="random">One</li>
    <li class="random">Two</li>
    <li class="random">Three</li>
    <li class="random">Four</li>
</ul>
```

Try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pxw06p64/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function such as the one below to generate a random color for you:

```js
function randColor() {
  var dig = '0123456789ABCDEF',
      col = '#';
  for(var i=0; i < 6; i++) {
    col += dig.charAt( Math.round( Math.random() * dig.length ) );
  }
  return col;
}
var li = $('<li/>'),
    ul = $('ul.list');
$.each([0,1,2,3,4,5,6], function() {
  ul.append( li.clone().attr('style','color:' + randColor() + ';').text( this ) );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function randColor() {
  var dig = '0123456789ABCDEF',
      col = '#';
  for(var i=0; i < 6; i++) {
    var thecolor = dig.charAt( Math.round( Math.random() * dig.length ) );
    while (thecolor < 333333)
    {
        thecolor = dig.charAt( Math.round( Math.random() * dig.length ) );
    }
    col += thecolor;
  }
  return col;
}
      $('.random').each(function(){
      $(this).css('color',randColor());
      });
      $('.random a').each(function(){
      $(this).css('color',randColor());
      });
```

Where '.random' is li class ".random"